# Neo4j: PID file not created while starting the database after upgrading 3.1.0 to 3.2.0

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases

I just updated the Neo4j 3.1.0 to 3.2.0. The install was successful. But once I tried to start the neo4j database I am getting the following issue:

> /usr/share/neo4j/bin/neo4j: line 411: /var/run/neo4j/neo4j.pid: No
>   such file or directory.

I am following instruction from here:

http://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/3.2/upgrade/deployment-upgrading/

Comment: I had a similar problem once. In my case there was no Neo4j folder, that is displayed in the error and I had to manually create it

Comment: I did. Although it says Neo4j starting and is assigning a pid. But Neo4j is not starting actually. Infact it is assigning pid everytime I run the command. Previously if a process is running and I run the command to start neo4j it would show a message that a process of neo4j is already running.

Comment: Well you can always take the easy way out and download the `.tar` version which is the most stable of all and has no such issues

Comment: i did a fresh install. same issue persisting.

Comment: I have the same issue.  I launched a clean neo4j 3.2.0 via the neo4j-docker image on AWS-ECS.  Neo4j starts cleanly and I can talk to it no problem.  However, when I try to import/upgrade a 2.3 database, then I get the same "line 411" error.  I used neo4j-admin (--mode database) to create the graph.db from the v2.3 data.  No error on that and the files are all there.  But neo4j won't start.  I can switch back to the installed graph.db and it works.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to happen when the neo4j startup script invokes java to launch neo4j and the launch fails. No pid is created, so you get the "/var/run/neo4j/neo4j.pid: No such file or directory".

But you have to look at the log file to see the actual error, e.g.:

```
   $ tail -n 50 /var/log/neo4j/neo4j.log  
    ...error stack ending with...
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.StoreLockException: Store and its lock file has been locked by another process: /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db/store_lock. Please ensure no other process is using this database, and that the directory is writable (required even for read-only access)
```

So in my case it was "lock file has been locked by another process".  Apparently when you first start an upgraded/seeded database, it can take a while to load.  So if you think it's hung and restart too soon--like I did--it can kick off another process.  I found 2 java processes still running via:

```
$ ps aux | grep java
```

I killed them off and restarted the server--this time I got a clean start with my upgraded db.

Comment: Yes this is exactly the error I am getting at the moment.

Comment: I used `killall -9 java` restarted the system. same issue.